# A rapidly-converging series of the Hasse–Weil L-function associated with an elliptic curve over rationals

Tags: dirichlet-series

I know that for some L-series there is still a rapidly-converging series. My question is about the existence of a such a series for the Dirichlet series of the Hasse–Weil L-function associated with an elliptic curve over rationals. A google search do not gives important answers.

Comment: Where do you want the series to converge rapidly? If it's the whole complex plane, such a series would be a proof of analytic continuation, which is as hard as modularity. Thus, you probably want to find the associated modular form and look for a rapidly converging series for the L-function of that modular form?

Comment: for any complex number s. I remamber that there is a rapidly converging series obtained by using Lavrik method, but I can't find it. 

Comment: Yes, there is a rapidly exponentially converging series for L(E,s) which relies on the functional equation and thus on modularity of E. This has been implemented, see e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207280

If you're more interested in values of s with high imaginary part, then you might need other methods, like the double exponential method. See Pascal Molin's PhD thesis http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~molinp/files/these.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the answer would be the so-called "approximate functional equation" for the $L$-function.  This of course takes as input the modularity of the Hasse-Weil zeta function, and gives rapidly convergent series representing it at any point.  I would expect Cremona's book on algorithms for modular elliptic curves to contain a description. Software like Pari/GP implements such algorithms (see the command elllseries).

Comment: Thank you Denis. I think that there is a rapidly converging series obtained by using Lavrik method, but I can't find it in any reference. 

Comment: See the book Analytic Number Theory by Iwaniec and Kowalski

Answer (score 2):

Also look at my paper: Computational methods and experiments in analytic number theory, in  Recent Perspectives in Random Matrix Theory and Number Theory.
Available here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412181v1.pdf
See section 3.4, example 5 which deals with elliptic curves.

Another reasonable reference is Akiyama and Tanigawa:http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2584959?uid=3739448&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=21102659822167